# Guava iterators for nested foreach

Tags: java, java-8, guava

I want to use guava iterator or java8 foreach(may be lambda expression) nested for loop and process some statements and return a long variable. Here is my code in native java. Please excuse my code may not efficient. I read over net accessing non final variables inside new java 8 foreach is not possible.

```
Long x = Long.valueOf(0);
Long y = Long.valueOf(0);
for(FirstLevel first : Levels) 
{
   if(first.getSecondLevels() == null) 
   {   
      x= x + getSomeValue(first);
   }
     for (SecondLevel second : first.getSecondLevels())
   {
      y = y + getSomeValue(second);
   }
}
return x + y;
```

I have tried but unable to return the values. Thanks in advance for help!

Comment: So the levels are just to keep track of the number of times through the loop?

Comment: And try something like x+=getSomeValue(x) //but should it be getSomeValue(first)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Couple things:

1. Before approaching "refactoring" like that one you ask, I really strongly recommend learning more "pure" Java (which I assume is the case here, @javalearner). For example you can use `long` literals instead of manually boxing values:

   ```
   long x = 0L;
   long y = 0L;
   ```

   Anyway...
2. using Guava won't help here - this is *the* imperative way of doing it, and with Java 7 + Guava you'd have to write awkward anonymous classes (i.e. `Function`s), which without language support is painful. Which brings me to...
3. Java 8 and Streams. This is probably the best way to go, but first you have to fix (?) your code and define actual problem - for example this statement `x= x + getSomeValue(x);` evaluates `x` each time and does not take `FirstLevel` into account (same is true for `y` and `SecondLevel`), so I assume what you really meant was `x =+ getSomeValue(firstLevel);`.

Having all that said - please be more specific what your problem really is.

**EDIT:**

After your clarification, using streams your code could look like this:

```
final long sum = levels.stream()
        .mapToLong(first -> getSomeValue(first) + first.getSecondLevels().stream().mapToLong(this::getSomeValue).sum())
        .sum();
```

or with some helper method:

```
final long s = levels.stream()
        .mapToLong(first -> getSomeValue(first) + getSecondLevelSum(first))
        .sum();

private long getSecondLevelSum(final FirstLevel first) {
    return first.getSecondLevels().stream().mapToLong(this::getSomeValue).sum();
}
```

Comment: Sorry. I was wrong. Your 3rd point is correct. I have edited now. If it is not possible on guava , is it possible in java 8 forEach like lamda expressions? Atleast i need to avoid native forloop syntax . Thanks for your response. Much appreciated

Comment: I thought using java8 would be efficients and looks good. Is there anyother way?

Comment: @Holger Yep, I've figured it out.

Comment: Few minutes earlier could have saved me some time ;^)

Comment: @Holger It was harder to see actual problem in original question before OP's edits :P

Comment: Thank you very much Holger and @Xaerxess. It solved my problem. Thanks for your time.

Comment: How can we filter to first condition if(first.getSecondLevels() == null) ? i tried applying for first stream but it is applying condition for second  loop as well. Thanks for help

Comment: If you can change code in `.getSecondLevels()`, don't ever return `null`, but rather empty collection ex. `Collections.emptyList()` (note that you'd get NNullPointerException in your original code using for each). If you can't, add null check like `first.getSecondLevels() == null ? 0L : first.getSecondLevels().stream().mapToLong(second -> getSomeValue(second))` but it's just uglier.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, there is no sense in using boxed `Long` values and even if you once need a boxed value, you don’t need to invoke `Long.valueOf`, Java already does that for you when converting a `long` primitive to a boxed `Long` object.

Further, since adding `long` values does not depend on the order of summands, there is no reason to maintain two variable throughout the operation, when you will add them at the end anyway:

```
long result=0;
for(FirstLevel first: Levels) {
    result += getSomeValue(first);
    for(SecondLevel second: first.getSecondLevels()) {
        result += getSomeValue(second);
    }
}
return result;
```

Note that the operator `+=` does the same as `result = result + …` here, but avoids the repetition of the target operand.

Assuming that both, `Levels` and the result of `getSecondLevels`, are collections you can write the same as Stream operation as

```
return Levels.stream()
    .mapToLong(first ->
        getSomeValue(first) + first.getSecondLevels().stream()
            .mapToLong(second -> getSomeValue(second)).sum())
    .sum();
```

or, alternatively

```
return Levels.stream()
    .flatMapToLong(first -> LongStream.concat(
        LongStream.of(getSomeValue(first)),
        first.getSecondLevels().stream().mapToLong(second -> getSomeValue(second))))
    .sum();
```

If `Levels` is an array, you have to replace `Levels.stream()` with `Arrays.stream(Levels)` and likewise, if `getSecondLevels()` returns an array, you have to replace `first.getSecondLevels().stream()` with `Arrays.stream(first.getSecondLevels())`

Comment: Nice trick with `LongStream#concat` and `Stream#flatMapToLong`!

Comment: @Xaerxess: yeah, the `flatMap` approach can become important for terminal operations not as trivial as summing.